# How to select checkbox and display values in textboxes and when checkbox not selected dont show value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a `Checkboxlist` , `Button` and two `TextBoxes`.

When selecting the first value in the `checkboxes` and press `button` I want to display it in one of the `textboxes` and when I uncheck the `checkboxes` I want the value to disappear from the `textboxes`.

```
if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                LabelFirstName.Text = CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                LabelFirstName.Text = "";
            }

            if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].Selected)
            {
                LabelLastName.Text = CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                LabelLastName.Text = "";
            }
```

This code work fine , but when unchecking the LabelFirstName.Text & LabelLastName.Text = ""; dont get empty

UPDATE

```
private void ButtonOKCheckBoxes()
    {
        EMPLOYEE theEmpl;
        using (var db = new knowitCVdbEntities())
        {
            theEmpl = (from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                       where p.username == strUserName
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (theEmpl != null)
        {
            PanelFullCv.Visible = true;
            LabelPleaseRegister.Visible = false;
            //CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].Text;
            if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                LabelFirstName.Text = theEmpl.firstname;
            }
            else
            {
                LabelFirstName.Text = "";
            }
            //CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].Text;
            if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].Selected)
            {
                LabelLastName.Text = theEmpl.lastname;
            }
            else
            {
                LabelLastName.Text = "";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: so what is your problem？

Comment: @Tianyun Ling when i select first checkbox it displays when i click both checkboxes both values disepears

Comment: have you checked my modified answer?

Comment: @Tianyun Ling yes but i just fingered out that i should not use =themEmply.lastname; i should use index of the value in the bound in checkboxlist how do i do that? – Kriistiian 2 mins ago edit 
 
 i will update the code i have made it work now but the problem is not that , when i unselect the checkboxes LabelFirstName.Text and LabelLastName.Text dont get emty

Comment: Sorry . I can't understand your question ! What you want ? can you explain clearly ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran i have updated in the top

Comment: Set AutoPostBack="true" property  in your CheckBoxList

Comment: @RameshRajendran i have dont that the values only dispears when i refresh the site

Comment: Are you create the checkboxlist from database or default ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran from database i get the data

Comment: @RameshRajendran i will update in the top i dont now

Comment: @RameshRajendran i made it work like this protected void CheckBoxPersonalInfo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].Selected == false)
            {
                LabelFirstName.Text = "";
            }
            else if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].Selected == false)
            {
                LabelLastName.Text = "";
            }

        }

Comment: @RameshRajendran but now the problem is that when i refresh the site the value in the textboxes looses it values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CheckedListBox.ItemCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event to monitor for Checked & Unchecked state of Item.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;

}

private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}        

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // set the data on text box
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice will work but I personally prefer compact version for small events :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should **really** try to follow some [Naming Guildelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Naming controls like classes is a very bad practice.

You could try it like this :

```
displayButton.Click += (s,e) => { 
displayTxtBox.Text = checkBoxPersonalInfo.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
};

checkBoxPersonalInfo_ItemCheck += (s,e) => { 
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
displayTxtBox.Clear();
};
```

Put both events in your `form_Load` what they will do is :

- `displayButton.Click` - When the button is clicked, the selected item will be displayed in the textbox.
- `checkBox.CheckedChanged` - When the checkbox is unchecked, the textbox will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Use !IsPostBack in this method

```
void page-load()
    {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         //Call your CheckBoxList Binding method   
    }
}
```

Comment: i get Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score -1):

your -1 and 0 in if condition is really confusing. And should the last part of the code be nested inside the if part?

Maybe you need something like:

```
if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[0].selected)
{
   LabelFirstName.Text = theEmpl.firstname;
}
else 
{
    LabelFirstName.Text = "";
}
if (CheckBoxPersonalInfo.Items[1].selected)
{
    LabelLastName.Text = theEmpl.lastname;
}
else 
{
    LabelLastName.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Your *answer* is really confusing.

Comment: @Tianyun Ling . I have Firstname and LastName displayed in checkboxlist , when user select Checkbox FirstName display that in the textbox or if the user unselect the checkbox the textbox should be emty , if the user select both , display both in textboxes , and so an if the user unselect both checkboxes dont display value in textboxes

Comment: @Tianyun Ling yes but i just fingered out that i should not use =themEmply.lastname; i should use index of the value in the bound in checkboxlist how do i do that?

Comment: @Tianyun Ling i will update the code i have made it work now but the problem is not that , when i unselect the checkboxes LabelFirstName.Text and LabelLastName.Text dont get emty